# Filter Firebase node by date

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

Hi have a Firebase node with dates set in each child. In my query, I want to remove all the events I have that happened in the past.

## Firebase

```
workouts
    -{key}
        - title:"My Workout"
        - date: "2017-04-1T10:30:27.250Z"
    -{key2}
        - title:"The Workout"
        - date: "2017-05-1T12:00:27.250Z"
```

## JS (Ionic2, angularfire2)

```
this.allEvents = this.af.database.list('/events', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'date'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to end .endAt(endTime) to limit the query

From the Firebase docs.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries

```
 var ref = db.ref("workouts");
  ref.orderByChild("date").endAt(endTime).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
  });
```

Then you would loop through the list and delete each and one

Comment: Thanks for you help but I needed to modify you tip:

let endTime = new Date().toISOString();
    
    this.allEvents = this.af.database.list('/events', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'date',
        startAt: endTime,
      }
    });

Comment: If the comment helped and solved your problem could you please mark it as such :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate through the array and compare the current date with the past date.
2. If it is an event that happened in the past, delete it. From the angularfire [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#firebasearray):

> $remove(recordOrIndex)
>
> Remove a record from the database and from the local array. This
>   method returns a promise that resolves after the record is deleted at
>   the server. It will contain a Firebase reference to the deleted
>   record. It accepts either an array index or a reference to an item
>   that exists in the array.

```
var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
var item = list[2];
list.$remove(item).then(function(ref) {
  ref.key === item.$id; // true
});
```